# Updating with changes to cell color

Tags: excel, vba

I have a code below that counts the number of coloured cells of a specific colour. The problem is that it does not recalculate when the cell colour changes. It only updates when I type something in the sheet. From what I understand this is due to `Application.Volatile` not triggering a recalculation due to cell colour changes. Is there a way to make my code trigger a recalculation when there are cell colour changes?

```
Function ColorFunction(rColor As Range, rRange As Range)
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim vResult
    
    Application.Volatile
    
    lCol = rColor.Interior.ColorIndex
    For Each rCell In rRange
        If rCell.Interior.ColorIndex = lCol Then
            vResult = 1 + vResult
        End If
    Next rCell
    
    ColorFunction = vResult
End Function
```

Comment: Since there is no event that triggers on color chang, there is no way to run that automatically. Note that color should never be used to transport information! **Always** use values to transport information and only use color for better visibilty of those values. Color should only be used to display information but never to transport it! • Excel is not made to get information out of color but you can easily get information out of values. Re-think your approach, it is a bad practice.

Comment: Note that `Application.Volatile` will only trigger the function to calculate on any re-calculation of the sheet. Color change does not trigger any re-calculation of the sheet because Excel does not assume a color to transport information and therefore there is no need to recalculate on color change. • Your function will always need a manual trigger (eg button) to run.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Yes I understand that it is easier to get information out of values... What Im doing here is that I have a sheet of data that are colour coded and now I want to count the number of cells of each specific colours. Thanks for your input, I may consider a manual trigger to run instead.

Comment: I'm confused; are these color chnages being set manually? You could wrangle a solution using the worksheet's [`SelectionChange` event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.selectionchange)...

Comment: @ashleedawg Yes, the data and colour coding is an input done by the user. Because the input is done by multiple people, I would rather the recalculation of the coloured cells to be automatic than requiring them to do additional steps. If I personally am the one using the function I would have just used it as it is... I will take a look at the link you provided to see if it helps. Thanks!

Comment: @John Would be an option then instead of letting people color something make a column where people add a value. Then take that value to color your values using conditional formatting (for better visibility). This way people enter values (still see visible color changes) and you are able to use `=COUNTIF()` to count the values. Much better solution.